# Proving injective/surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $P = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. We define a relation on $P$ as follows: $(x,y) \sim (z,w)$ if and only if there exist $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ such that $x = \lambda z$ and $y = \lambda w$.

Define the function $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to {^{P}\big/_{\sim}}$ by $\phi(t) = [(t,1)]$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, where $[(t,1)]$ is the equivalence class represented by $(t,1)$. Prove that $\phi$ is injective but not surjective. Find out all the equivalence classes that are not in the range of $\phi$.

This is what I have got so far:

$$\phi(t) = [(t,1)], t \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$\phi(t) = (\lambda t, \lambda), t \in \mathbb{R}$$

Injective proof:

$$\phi(t_1) = \phi(t_2)$$
$$(\lambda t_1, \lambda) = (\lambda t_2, \lambda)$$
$$\implies \lambda t_1 = \lambda t_2$$
$$\implies t_1 = t_2, \lambda \neq 0.$$

Not surjective proof:

$\phi$ is surjective if for any $a \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ there exists $b \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ so that $\phi(b) = a$. However, for $b = (1,1)$, we have

$$\phi(b) = \phi(1,1)$$
$$= (\lambda,\lambda),$$

which only equals to $(t,1)$ if $\lambda = 1$. Thus, $\phi$ is not surjective.

Equivalence classes that are not in the range of $\phi$:

$$(t,u), t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}, u \neq \frac{1}{\lambda}.$$

Have I done this correctly?

Edit:

Injective:

Suppose $\phi(a) = \phi(b)$. This means that $[(a,1)] = [(b,1)]$, implying that $(a,1)$ and $(b,1)$ belong to the same equivalence class. By the definition of the equivalence relation, this means there exists a non-zero $\lambda$ such that $a = \lambda \cdot b$ and $1 = \lambda \cdot 1$.

Since $\lambda \cdot 1 = 1$, we have $\lambda = 1$, thus, $a = \lambda b = b$, which proves that $\phi$ is injective.

Surjective:

Consider the point $(1,0)$. We want to show that there is no real number $t$ such that $\phi(t) = [(t,1)]$ represents the equivalence class containing $(1,0)$.

Suppose, for contradiction, that there exists a real number $t$ such that $\phi(t) = [(t,1)]$ represents the equivalence class containing $(1,0)$. This implies that $(1,0)$ is related to $(t,1)$ under the relation defined, i.e. there exists a non-zero $\lambda$ such that $1 = \lambda \cdot t$ and $0 = \lambda \cdot 1$.

Since $0 = \lambda \cdot 1, \lambda = 0$. However, this contradicts the assumption that $\lambda \neq 0$. Therefore, $\phi$ is not surjective.

Equivalence class that is not in the range of $\phi$: $[(x,0)]$ for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Not following your proof that $\phi$ is not surjective.  $\phi(1)=[(1,1)]$ gets you the class $[(\lambda, \lambda)]$ so that element is in the image.  Also, $\phi$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ so I'm not sure what $\phi(1,1)$ means.  Nor do I understand your classification of the classes outside the image of $\phi$.

Comment: I think it might be worth a try to do this geometrically rather than algebraically. Draw a couple of equivalence classes. See what they look like, and learn how you can find the relevant equivalence class given a point. Draw $\phi(t)$ for a couple of values of $t$ (say from -3 to 3) to get a feel for how the map works.

Comment: Should say:  your prove of injectivity is a bit hand wavy.  It is not true that $\phi(t)=(\lambda t, \lambda)$.  What would $\lambda$ be as a value?  It is true that $\phi(t)$ is the equivalence class of $(\lambda t, \lambda)$ for any non-zero $\lambda$, but it's not so clear how to use your argument with sets instead of single values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you already know or have established that $\sim$ is in fact an equivalence relation.

Assume $\phi(t)=\phi(s)$.  To prove injectivity, we need to prove $t=s$.

By the definition of $\phi$, we have that $[(t, 1)]=[(s, 1)]$.  By the definition of an equivalence class, this tells us that $(t, 1) \sim (s, 1)$.  (This is the step that allows you to go from equivalence classes, which are hard to work with, to specific ordered pairs, which are easy to work with.)

By the definition of $\sim$, we therefore know that for some $\lambda \neq 0$, we have $t= \lambda s$ and $1= \lambda 1$.  But the second equation tells us that $\lambda=1$, so the first equation then tells us that $t=s$ and we have proved injectivity.

To prove that $\phi$ is not surjective, we need to find an equivalence class that's not in its range.  Note that *almost* every equivalence class $[(x, y)]$ is uniquely characterized by $\frac xy$ and in fact $[(x, y)]=\phi(\frac xy)$ (in other words, $(x, y) \sim (\frac xy, 1)$, as you can see by letting $\lambda = \frac 1y$).  Does this help you identify an equivalence class that's not in the range of $\phi$?  Your example is not correct, as noted in the comments, because $[(1, 1)]=\phi(1)$ is in the range of $\phi$.  Hint:  Why did I use the word "almost" above?

Comment: Thanks, if I have understood it correctly, the only equivalence class that is not in the range is (0,1)?

Comment: @VincentN  $(0, 1)$ is an ordered pair, not an equivalence class, although it's a member of an equivalence class.  You want to talk about $[(0, 1)]$.  Until you are extremely comfortable with the concepts, you should be careful to be precise in your notation because that precision helps you learn and understand the concepts.  But in any event, what's $\phi(0)$?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to say $[(0,1])$ instead of $(0,1)$, $phi(0) = [(0,1)]$, but since $P = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$, so it is not in the range of $\phi$?

Comment: @VincentN Why do you think $(0, 1) \notin P$?  Is $(0, 1)$ an ordered pair of real numbers?  Is $(0, 1) = (0, 0)$?

Comment: Oh, I mistakenly read it as both values cannot be 0 instead of $(0,0)$, with the hint, I think $[(x,0)]$ for $x \neq 0$ would be the answer?

Comment: @VincentN Correct.  Don't just say it, though.  Prove it.

Comment: Thanks, I have edit my question to include it.

Comment: @VincentN Look again at your write-up.  It's not correct.

Comment: Sorry, would you mind pointing out the error?

Comment: @VincentN The penultimate paragraph.

Comment: I have changed that, I hope it is correct this time.

Comment: @VincentN Yes, it's correct now.